# Adobe AIR and ACS3.0 - best tools for testing native apps?

Tags: actionscript-3, testing, air, adobe

i developed an Adobe Flash cs6 ,AIR  for ios native app and i would like to ask  if anyone has to suggest any straight forward tools for functional testing or unit and maybe other types of testing .

Comment: do you mean debugging?

Comment: no , i have already solved all my bugs  , i am just currently looking for any automated tool for testing. adobe air applications or actionscript . I have used the 'SWF inspector' so far.